# Get Current Activity in Android Application

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to know in which activity is currently running in my appliction . I'm used **View view =(View)getCurrentFocus();** but it returns null value. Is there any function like **getCurrentActivity()**?

Thanks in advance

Comment: where are you? Inside the scope of the Activity class? If `this` is accessible?

Comment: "I want to know in which activity is currently running in my appliction" -- why?

Comment: Because I want to check that activity finished or not..

Comment: Yes... I used the Context, by that we can get which activity is running now.

Answer (score -1):

To get the Class name of the current activity.

```
this.getLocalClassName()
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, only edited. Although the answer is probably not too good, because to me it was shown in [low quality posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/low-quality-posts/info "what's this") review queue